# Desktop PC won't turn on, motherboard light is on

Tags: boot, motherboard, power-supply, power, desktop-computer

**Background:**
Desktop PC was working last week. I moved/hid it to prevent it from being stolen in case someone broke into my house as I was away, now it won't turn on.

**Problem description:**

- computer won't turn on despite motherboard light being on
- when I press the power button, the power button light turns on very briefly
- during that brief time none of the motherboard components (other than light) seem to receive any power as case fan, CPU fan, GPU fan all remain off
- motherboard doesn't beep

**What I know works**:

- the power / power strip as I have another working PC plugged to it
- PSU paperclip test: put a paperclip on the main 24-pin cable ([like so](https://help.corsair.com/hc/article_attachments/360063091352/psu_24-pin_power_test.png)): the PSU starts, and so does my external SATA drive connected directly to the PSU.

**What I checked**:

- PC case isn't touching any metal
- All components (GPU, RAM etc...) are well mounted, no component seem loose
- All case buttons (e.g. power button) seem properly connected

**Does anybody have any troubleshooting tips which don't involve replacing hardware (e.g. replacing the various parts one by one like the power supply which I will try after any suggestions here)?**

Comment: To start with re-seat all components like RAM, PSU Cables, GPU etc and check. Do one at a time. Check if PSU turns on by doing a basic paperclip test. You can google for search string `PSU Paperclip test` to know how to do it.

Comment: OK PSU paperclip test is working, checking all components one more time

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @patkim's suggestion on `PSU Paperclip test` which allowed me to rule out the `PSU` without a spare one.

In the end the **problem seemed to be caused by one of the HDMI/Display cables as unplugging/replugging those cables fixed the issue. I suspect a contact with the case.**

**Setup:**
I run a 4-display setup with a GeForce GTX 1660 on a Fractal Design Define R5 tower. Somehow there's very little space for me to plug the cables as the HDMI/Display ports are very close to the horizontal separators at the back of the case.

**Troubleshooting:**

- Checked again that all components were well mounted on the motherboard, tested again =>  no difference
- Removed all hdmi/display cables, tested again => it worked!
- Plugged hdmi/display cables back, and it kept working

**Hence my conclusion that it was a contact issue between cables and the case** as I can't see what other issue unplugging/plugging back could have resolved, but **if you have suggestions I'm all ears.**

Comment: PSU paperclip test is a very basic test just to confirm if PSU turns on or not in first place. A PSU that turns on in paperclip test may still be faulty in such a way that it may not turn on under load of the full system. But this basic test helps to confirm if PSU is dead or not.

Comment: Got it, thanks for the additional info